# Update view between functions that are executed when button pressed

Tags: asynchronous, button, view, swift4, xcode9

I have 3 Labels and a UIButton in my view. After I press the UIButton some functions are being executed and I want them to do the following:

As soon as Picture 1 is finished downloading Label 1 shall be updated, after Picture 2 is finished downloading Label 2 shall be updated and so on.

The problem is: My view, so my labels, are all updated at once after all functions are resolved...

I read about asynchronous tasks - but in my understanding I don't need it because I don't mind if the user can't click any Buttons as long as all the functions are executed, all I want is the view(labels) to update while executing the functions, not only after everything is completed...

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func ButtonLoadPictures(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Picture1
    downloadImage()
    LabelResult1.text = "Ready"

    // Picture2
    downloadImage()
    LabelResult2.text = "Ready"

    // Picture3
    downloadImage()
    LabelResult3.text = "Ready"


}
```

Edit:

Because I was asked for the code inside downloadImage():
downloadImage was just a placeholder for a lot of functions I have in this place. But in my understanding it is not relevant what the code specifically is. In case it is, I have added an example for downloadImage(). The problem is I don't want to update my labels all at once after execution of all functions, but after each time after "donwnloadImage()"

```
func downloadImage(){
        guard let myURL = URL(string: myLink) else {                                                 
            print("Error: \(myLink) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
            return
        }

        do {
            myLinkHTMLcontent = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .ascii)
            print(myLinkHTMLcontent)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
```

Comment: please post code of function `downloadImage()`

Comment: downloadImage() was just a placeholder for a bunch of functions, and I don't think it makes any difference what they are in detail.

But I will insert a more detailed example in my post above

Answer (score 0):

The path I would choose in this case is asynchronous tasks in your logic, and use completion handlers, something like this:

```
IBAction func ButtonLoadPictures(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Picture1
    downloadImage(){ result in 
        self.LabelResult1.text = result
    }

    // Picture2
    downloadImage(){ result in 
        self.LabelResult2.text = result
    }

    // Picture3
    downloadImage(){ result in 
        self.LabelResult3.text = result
    }
}

func downloadImage(completion: @escaping(String) -> ()){
    // all your logic
    completion("ready")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will look into this in the next days/weeks! (Quite busy right now with other things...)